# Invoke isn't working on a class

Tags: c#, windows, forms, invoke

i have a class that i use delegate and invoke list this:

```
delegate void delSetMsg(string message, bool burlar);

public void setMsg(string message, bool burlar)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new delSetMsg(setMsg), message, burlar);
    }
    else
    {
        if (burlar == true || canWrite() == true)
        {
            frm_server frm_server = new frm_server();
            frm_server.rtbox_servermsg.Text += message + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

and the program show me this error CS1061, to the "InvokeRequired" and "BeginInvoke". I'm using this `using`s:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

The error CS1061 says: "'serverclass' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInvoke' and no extension method 'BeginInvoke' accepting a first argument of type 'serverclass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". serverclass is the name of my class.

Comment: Your class doesn't inherit from `Control`, so there's no reason to call `Invoke` on it. And as far as I can tell, you won't need to invoke on a new form.

Comment: but the thing is that i need to do this condition test, that is a way to call Control on a class?

Comment: My point is that you *don't* need to do that check. The whole point of `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` is so that the code runs on the correct thread for that particular UI control. In this case, there is no control in question, and as such any thread will do. Again, as far as I can see, you don't need that check at all. If anything, the check would be on `frm_server.InvokeRequired`, but I am almost positive that you won't have any issues with the correct context on a new form.

Comment: oh thx, i'll work on that, and if you want to post this comment as a answer i would check it.